# Server Memory full - fclose missing

Tags: php, apache, memory, server, fclose

I have a PHP-Code like:

```
$timestamp = time();
echo time();
echo "<br>";
$datenbank = "timestamp.txt";
$datei = fopen($datenbank, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($datei, $timestamp) or die("Unable to write file!");
```

but I forget fclose(). Now, I have no more memory on the server. Could this be the reason?

Comment: What error message are you getting from the server?. Do you have permissions to write to the directory or file?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. It is not good practice to leave files open like that, but PHP will close the file when your script ends.

Comment: But where is the problem? I only use 6,6GB of 23GB..

df:
/dev/sda2             23688348  22488736         0 100% /

du -sh /*:
6,6G

Comment: There's a distinction here between memory and memory. Your question and this answer (and most technical usage) seems to imply RAM, where your comment implies disk space.

Comment: So what can I do now?

Comment: Check that the above code is not in some sort of loop that means fwrite is being called endlessly. Check the file system on your server for anything that's taking up a lot of space.